# Is there any way we could have more information about tags in /questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

In the [`/tags` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags), the following information is returned for a specific tag:

```
{
  "name": "c#",
  "count": 262613,
  "is_required": false,
  "is_moderator_only": false,
  "has_synonyms": true
}
```

`is_required` indicates that the tag is part of the set of required tags for the site. This is great, but leads to problems when trying to indicate this using the data returned from the [`/questions` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions). The only data returned by this route is the tag name. Currently there is no method to fetch additional data for a specific tag.

Comment: Can't you just make another query to the /tags route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... no, I'm [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)-ing this.  Fetching that sort of data for each tag on each question becomes unpleasantly slow when you're dealing with batches of questions (which most request are).

However, you are correct that there's no good way to grab additional data about a tag given just it's name.  I've added the [/tags/{tags}/info](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/tags-by-name) method to alleviate this.

For the specific "mimic the site styling" cases, I've added [/tags/required](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/required-tags) and [/tags/moderator-only](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/moderator-only-tags).  I suggest fetching and caching the result for quite a while (a day or even longer) since we rarely add or change either moderator or required tags.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) on those.  They've been deployed already.

Also, congratulations on getting what is probably the last V2.0 [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) in.  Feature freeze is fast approaching.

Comment: How does the `/tags/{tags}/info` method differ from the `/tags` with `inname`? Also why not just `/tags/{tags}` (not that I mind just should this method be used differently to others?)

Comment: @Jonathan: I don't think `inname` allows for multiple tags.

Comment: Thanks for implementing this. Caching *all* tags is prohibitive, but caching only moderator or required tags is sensible.